# Formar un json en php

Tags: php, json

Como se podría formar un `json` así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo hago de esta menra pero no se como completar lo que sigue del json :

```
<?php
  $respuestas = array("fecha"=>'8850',"glosa"=>'8900',"gasto_no_deducible"=>'8875','prefijo'=>'512');
  $json = json_encode($respuestas);
  echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: puedes agregar el texto en vez de la imagen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata de hacerlo de este modo, es un ejemplo:

```
$data = array(
    array("valor1" => 1, "valor2" => 2, "valor3" => array(
        array("valora" => 1, "valorb" => 2),
        array("valora" => 3, "valorb" => 4),
        array("valora" => 5, "valorb" => 6),
        array("valora" => 7, "valorb" => 8)
    ))
);

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Que me da como resultado esto:

```
[
    {
        "valor1": 1,
        "valor2": 2,
        "valor3": [
            {
                "valora": 1,
                "valorb": 2
            },
            {
                "valora": 3,
                "valorb": 4
            },
            {
                "valora": 5,
                "valorb": 6
            },
            {
                "valora": 7,
                "valorb": 8
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Explicación**

- Creo un array multidimensional, por ello hay una instrucción `array` que envuelve a los demás.
- Creo un segundo `array` interno que que tiene las claves y valores de: **fecha, glosa, gasto_no_dducible, prefijo y detalles**
- Para formar el grupo de valores, que estan ligados a la clave **detalles**, hacemos esto: `detalles: array(.....`, de modo que el valor de dicha clave serña una colección de registros, los 4 grupos que tiene dentro.

**Tu ejercicio**

```
$data = array(
    array("fecha" => "16/05/2017", "glosa" => "Asiento VIP", "gasto_no_deducible" => 0, "prefijo" => "ASI",  "detalles" => array(
        array("cuenta_id" => "dfsdsf", "valor" => 10, "tipo" => "D", "centro_costo_id" => "dfssdffsd"),
        array("cuenta_id" => "dfsdsf", "valor" => 150, "tipo" => "D", "centro_costo_id" => "dfssdffsd"),
        array("cuenta_id" => "dfsdsf", "valor" => 100, "tipo" => "H", "centro_costo_id" => "dfssdffsd"),
        array("cuenta_id" => "dfsdsf", "valor" => 150, "tipo" => "H", "centro_costo_id" => "dfssdffsd"),
    ))
);

echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Dando como resultado:

```
[
    {
        "fecha": "16/05/2017",
        "glosa": "Asiento VIP",
        "gasto_no_deducible": 0,
        "prefijo": "ASI",
        "detalles": [
            {
                "cuenta_id": "dfsdsf",
                "valor": 10,
                "tipo": "D",
                "centro_costo_id": "dfssdffsd"
            },
            {
                "cuenta_id": "dfsdsf",
                "valor": 150,
                "tipo": "D",
                "centro_costo_id": "dfssdffsd"
            },
            {
                "cuenta_id": "dfsdsf",
                "valor": 100,
                "tipo": "H",
                "centro_costo_id": "dfssdffsd"
            },
            {
                "cuenta_id": "dfsdsf",
                "valor": 150,
                "tipo": "H",
                "centro_costo_id": "dfssdffsd"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Necesario**

> Por último puedes usar la constante de PHP llamada `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` que evitará escapar las diagonales.

Además de lo anterior.

**Opcional**

> También uso `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` para poder sacar el resultado de manera indentada y similar a tu imagen, **importante recuerda separar las 2 constantes anteriores por el símbolo de |** aunque esta constante no es estrictamente necesaria

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que debes hacer es meter pequeños `array` dentro de un `array` principal, al hacer el `json_encode` se convertirán en un solo `array` de objetos:

```
<?php 

$respuestas = [
    "fecha"=>'8850',
    "glosa"=>'8900',
    "gasto_no_deducible"=>'8875',
    'prefijo'=>'512',
    "detalles"=>[
        [
            "cuenta_id"=>"MZN.....",
            "valor"=>10,
            "tipo"=>"D",
            "centro_costo_id"=>"EGO..."
        ],
        [
            "cuenta_id"=>"x5o.....",
            "valor"=>150,
            "tipo"=>"D",
            "centro_costo_id"=>"EGO..."
        ],
        [
            "cuenta_id"=>"EGO.....",
            "valor"=>100,
            "tipo"=>"H",
            "centro_costo_id"=>""
        ],
        [
            "cuenta_id"=>"qlw.....",
            "valor"=>150,
            "tipo"=>"H",
            "centro_costo_id"=>""
        ]
    ]
];
$json = json_encode($respuestas);
echo $json;

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que crear un array de arrays para el elemento que falta, algo así:

```
<?php
  $respuestas = array("fecha"=>'8850',"glosa"=>'8900',"gasto_no_deducible"=>'8875','prefijo'=>'512', 'detalles' => array(array('cuenta_id' => '123a', 'valor' => 10),array('cuenta_id' => '123b', 'valor' => 11) ));
  $json = json_encode($respuestas);
  echo $json;
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]