# Quiero formar un json en php con la siguiente estructura

Tags: php, json, array

Buenas estoy consumiendo información de mi base de datos y creando un json

```
$array_datos = [];
        $array_vacaciones = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($personaAreas); $i++) {
            $nombreUsuario = $personaAreas[$i]['NOMBRE'];
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($vacacionesMesPersonas); $j++) {
                if ($vacacionesMesPersonas[$j]['COD_PERSONAL'] == $personaAreas[$i]['COD_PERSONAL']) {
                    $array_vacaciones = array(
                        $vacaciones => array(
                            "from" =>  $vacacionesMesPersonas[$j]['FECHA_INICIO'],
                            "to" => $vacacionesMesPersonas[$j]['FECHA_FIN'],
                            "customClass" => "ganttOrange"
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
            $data = array(
                array("name" => "$nombreUsuario",
                "values" => array($array_vacaciones))
            );

            echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            
        }
```

dicho json no se llega a formar como quiero:

```
        [
    {
        "name": "Alejandro Santana",
        "values": [
            {
                "from": "21\/12\/20",
                "to": "21\/12\/20",
                "customClass": "ganttOrange"
            }
        ]
    }
][
    {
        "name": "Briseida Verona",
        "values": [
            {
                "from": "28\/12\/20",
                "to": "31\/12\/20",
                "customClass": "ganttOrange"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

tanto $personaAreas como $vacacionesMesPersonas me devuelven un array y con dicha informaciónn quiero crear la siguiente estructura en json:

$vacacionesMesPersonas me devuelve un array con todas las vacaciones del mes que han sido puestas

```
[{
"name": "pepe",
"values": [
  { "from": "/Date(1604188800000)/", "to": "/Date(1604188800000)/",  "customClass": "ganttOrange" },
  { "from": "/Date(1606694400000)/", "to": "/Date(1606694400000)/",  "customClass": "ganttGreen" }
]
},{
"name": "pepo",
"values": [
  { "from": "/Date(1604188800000)/", "to": "/Date(1604188800000)/",  "customClass": "ganttRed" },
  { "from": "/Date(1606694400000)/", "to": "/Date(1606694400000)/",  "customClass": "ganttRed" }
]
}]
```

Soy nuevo en esto disculpen si no me expreso muy bien

Comment: He encontrado una posible respuesta quí [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/269580/formar-un-json-en-php)

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema, el formato de fecha? Por favor edita la pregunta para especificar cómo obtienes la información, si es de base de datos, agrega también la estructura de la tabla y el contenido de una fila.

Comment: Hola buenas, simplemente quiero formar la estructura del array de la siguiente forma : [{},{},{}] . no puedo mostrarte como vienen los datos de la base de datos porque tengo información delicada. de todas formas de ambas tablas me devuelve un array que intento unificar

Answer (score 0):

ya tengo la solución para que se muestre como quiero sería de la siguiente forma:

```
$array_datos = [];
$array_vacaciones = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($personasAreas); $i++) {
    $nombreUsuario = $personasAreas[$i]['NOMBRE'];
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($vacacionesMesPersonas); $j++) {
        if ($vacacionesMesPersonas[$j]['COD_PERSONAL'] == $personasAreas[$i]['COD_PERSONAL']) {
            $array_vacaciones[] = array(
                "from" =>  $vacacionesMesPersonas[$j]['FECHA_INICIO'],
                "to" => $vacacionesMesPersonas[$j]['FECHA_FIN'],
                "customClass" => "ganttOrange"
            );
        }
    }
    $data = array(
        "name" => "$nombreUsuario",
        "values" => $array_vacaciones
    );

    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

es decir hay que añadir los dos corchetes para que se concatenen

```
$array_vacaciones[] = array(
                "from" =>  $vacacionesMesPersonas[$j]['FECHA_INICIO'],
                "to" => $vacacionesMesPersonas[$j]['FECHA_FIN'],
                "customClass" => "ganttOrange"
            );
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien un saludo!